# Create a new pandas column that uses an existing columns to fill previous rows and group by based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have below dataset with me :

```
myid id_1   Date       group  new_id   
100  1    1-Jan-2020    A              
100  2    3-Jan-2020    A              
100  3    4-Jan-2020    A      101     
100  4    15-Jan-2020   A              
100  5    20-Feb-2020   A              
200  6    3-Jan-2020    B              
200  7    8-Feb-2020    B              
200  8    9-Feb-2020    B      102     
200  9    25-Mar-2020   B              
200  9    26-Jan-2020   B
```

I wanted to create a column named ns.

The column "ns" needs to be created in a way that it uses myid, Date and new_id.

1. If the difference b/w the previous date is greater than 30 and it belongs to the same my_id, the value should be incremented, otherwise should retain the same value
2. If new_id is not null and the it will share the same value as the previous row and the next row will have an increment.
3. For every my_id the value starts from 1

Expected output :

```
myid id_1   Date       group  new_id      ns
100  1    1-Jan-2020    A               1
100  2    3-Jan-2020    A               1
100  3    4-Jan-2020    A      101      1
100  4    15-Jan-2020   A               2
100  5    20-Jan-2020   A               3
200  6    3-Jan-2020    B               1
200  7    8-Feb-2020    B               2
200  8    9-Feb-2020    B      102      2
200  9    25-Mar-2020   B               3
200  9    26-Mar-2020   B               4
```

I have used  `df.groupby('CMID')['Date'].diff()` and `df.groupby('CMID')['PlanID'].bfill()` , `np.where` to create multiple dummy columns in order to achieve this and still working on it , please let me know if there's a better way to go about this ?

Comment: `If the difference b/w the previous date is greater than 30 and it belongs to the same my_id, the value should be change to the serial no at that location, otherwise should retain the same value` - Not understand, why is change to `1` row with `id_1=2,3`  and to `7` `id_1=8`?

Comment: Because difference greater for `30 days` is in `id_1=5,7` only.

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for replying and I tried my best explaining what I want to achieve.  For "jk" calculation,  it retains the same values if the date diff is not greater than 30 days and the previous row doesnot have 'new_id' as not null.  I am not using "id_1" at all but instead using myid for grouping.

Comment: HI @jezrael, I have updated my question. let me know if you are able to understand it now, thank you

Comment: So for `myid=100` is no value greater like `30days` ? Why are different some datetimes in ouput and input?

Comment: Hi @jezrael that's correct, there is no value greater like ```30days``` for ```myid=100``` and sorry for the datetimes it was a typo